# Locking with synchronized method on same instance

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm running this code:

```
public class SyncMethods {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new SyncMethods().syncMethodsInvoker();
    }

    public void syncMethodsInvoker() {

        System.out.println("inside syncMethodsInvoker()");

        Thread t1 = new SyncMethodThread(this);
        Thread t2 = new SyncMethodThread(this);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    synchronized void firstSyncMethod(String threadName) {

        System.out.format("begin firstSyncMethod() %s\n", threadName);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.format("looping firstSyncMethod() %s #%s for object %s\n", threadName, i, this);
            try {
                this.wait(100);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("end firstSyncMethod() " + threadName);
    }

    private class SyncMethodThread extends Thread {

        final private SyncMethods sm;

        public SyncMethodThread(SyncMethods sm) {
            this.sm = sm;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.format("inside run() %s, sm: %s\n", this.getName(), sm);
            sm.firstSyncMethod(this.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

And i'm getting this output:

```
inside syncMethodsInvoker()
inside run() Thread-0, sm: multithreading.SyncMethods@6189a0b9
inside run() Thread-1, sm: multithreading.SyncMethods@6189a0b9
begin firstSyncMethod() Thread-0
looping firstSyncMethod() Thread-0 #0 for object multithreading.SyncMethods@6189a0b9
begin firstSyncMethod() Thread-1
looping firstSyncMethod() Thread-1 #0 for object multithreading.SyncMethods@6189a0b9
looping firstSyncMethod() Thread-0 #1 for object multithreading.SyncMethods@6189a0b9
looping firstSyncMethod() Thread-1 #1 for object multithreading.SyncMethods@6189a0b9
looping firstSyncMethod() Thread-0 #2 for object multithreading.SyncMethods@6189a0b9
looping firstSyncMethod() Thread-1 #2 for object multithreading.SyncMethods@6189a0b9
looping firstSyncMethod() Thread-1 #3 for object multithreading.SyncMethods@6189a0b9
looping firstSyncMethod() Thread-0 #3 for object multithreading.SyncMethods@6189a0b9
looping firstSyncMethod() Thread-1 #4 for object multithreading.SyncMethods@6189a0b9
looping firstSyncMethod() Thread-0 #4 for object multithreading.SyncMethods@6189a0b9
end firstSyncMethod() Thread-1
end firstSyncMethod() Thread-0
```

As both threads are locking on the same instance I was expecting the *looping* to go something like this:

```
looping firstSyncMethod() Thread-0 #0 for object multithreading.SyncMethods@6189a0b9
looping firstSyncMethod() Thread-0 #1 for object multithreading.SyncMethods@6189a0b9
looping firstSyncMethod() Thread-0 #2 for object multithreading.SyncMethods@6189a0b9
looping firstSyncMethod() Thread-0 #3 for object multithreading.SyncMethods@6189a0b9
looping firstSyncMethod() Thread-0 #4 for object multithreading.SyncMethods@6189a0b9
looping firstSyncMethod() Thread-1 #0 for object multithreading.SyncMethods@6189a0b9
looping firstSyncMethod() Thread-1 #1 for object multithreading.SyncMethods@6189a0b9
looping firstSyncMethod() Thread-1 #2 for object multithreading.SyncMethods@6189a0b9
looping firstSyncMethod() Thread-1 #3 for object multithreading.SyncMethods@6189a0b9
looping firstSyncMethod() Thread-1 #4 for object multithreading.SyncMethods@6189a0b9
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Shouldn't `this` implement `Runnable`?

Comment: Calling `this.wait()` releases the lock on `this`. If you want to retain the lock while "waiting" a bit, use `Thread.sleep()` (or `TimeUnit.MILLIS.sleep()`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of this line `this.wait(100);` which causes the current thread to release the lock and wait for 100ms. So the other thread can acquire the lock.

[Object.wait(long)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long))

> This method causes the current thread (call it T) to place itself in the wait set for this object and then to **relinquish any and all synchronization claims on this object**. Thread T becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant until one of four things happens: ...

Complementing the answer with [erickson's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45179027/locking-with-synchronized-method-on-same-instance/45179131#comment77326722_45179027) on the question: If you want to retain the lock while "waiting" a bit, use `Thread.sleep()` (or `TimeUnit.MILLIS.sleep()`).